# Next.JS svgr command fails Type 'TrustedHTML' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have some typescript error I have when I run yarn run build on my turborepo I don't understand.

This is the command that fails:
svgr --typescript --no-dimensions --out-dir ./assets -- ./assets

I'm using Next.JS version 12.1.6 and React 18.2.0.

This is the error I get from the console:

[image]

When I hover my mouse over the corresponding svg icon, this is what I get:

[image]

I have this error on all my svg icons.

I really don't understand where it's coming from as everything works fine with npm run dev.

Edit:

SvgBrandColor code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { SVGProps } from "react";

const SvgBrandColor = (props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 59 59"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    {...props}
  >
...
  </svg>
);
```

export default SvgBrandColor;

Comment: would you please share the code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fauzanadhim, there's no code per say, only thing I can say is the next build command fails to run with the error I mentioned in my question

Comment: That's still not showing the full code for the component. Please copy/paste the full code as is, don't omit anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, the error is being caused by the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute. I worked around it by omitting it:

```
export type MySvgProps = Omit<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, "dangerouslySetInnerHTML">
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your react dependencies :

```
"dependencies":{
    ...
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    ...
},
"devDependencies":{
    ...
    "@types/react": "18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    ...
}
```